# If I delete only a directory what happens to it's contents android

Tags: java, android, io

What will happens to the contents of a directory if i delete it but not it's contents?

```
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    // Switch based on menu option clicked
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.context_delete:
        selectedPaths = mAdapter.getCurrentPaths();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedPaths.size(); i++) {
            File f = new File(selectedPaths.get(i));
            f.delete();
            mAdapter.remove(selectedPaths.get(i));
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        selectedPaths.clear();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Delete successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
        return true;
```

for example what would happen to the files if this code ran on a directory containing files? Would the files be deleted too? Or are they stuck in limbo somewhere..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> boolean java.io.File.delete()
>
> If this pathname denotes a directory, then the directory must be empty
>   in order to be deleted.